# scrolling responsive footer is overlapping the body content on desktop

Tags: html, css

Desktop view it is overlapping my body content at the end of the body
[image: Desktop view it is overlapping my body content at the end of the body]

but in mobile mode it is fine
[image: but in mobile mode it is fine]

My html footer code

```
    <?php
include('connect.php');
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Da Centro Uk and accs</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/ccfde701f7.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div name="Navigation">
    <nav>
      <div class="logo">Da Centro Uk and Accs</div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="click">
      <label for="click" class="menu-btn">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </label>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="index1.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Tee1.php">Tee</a></li>
        <li><a href="Jeans1.php">Jeans</a></li>
        <li><a href="Acs1.php">Accessories</a></li>
        <li><a href="Account.php">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>  
  </div>
  <table>
    <?php 
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM uk ";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $count = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
      if($count==3) 
      {
       print "</tr>";
       $count = 0;
     }
     if($count==0)
       print "<tr>";
     print "<td>";
     ?>
     <div>
      <form method="post">
        <div>
          <?php echo "<center>"."<img style='width: 480px; height: 360px;' src='img/" . $row["ukPic"]. "'>"."<center>"?>
          <h5>Product Name: <?php echo $row["ukName"]; ?></h5>
          <h5>Price: <?php echo $row["ukPrice"]; ?></h5>
          <h5>Stocks: <?php echo $row["ukQuant"]; ?></h5>
          <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="<?php echo $row["ukName"]; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" value="<?php echo $row["ukPrice"]; ?>">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <?php
    $count++;
    print "</td>";
  }
  if($count>0)
   print "</tr>";
 ?>
</table>
<div name="Footer">
  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="footer-addr">
      <h1 class="footer-logo">cdj</h1>
      <h2>Contact</h2>
      <address>
        cdj<br>
        <a class="footer-btn" href="mailto:example@gmail.com">Email Us</a>
      </address>
    </div>
    <ul class="footer-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <h2 class="nav-title">Media</h2>
        <ul class="nav-ul">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Online</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Print</a>
          </li>    
          <li>
            <a href="#">Alternative Ads</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>     
      <li class="nav-item">
        <h2 class="nav-title">Legal</h2>    
        <ul class="nav-ul">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
          </li>    
          <li>
            <a href="#">Terms of Use</a>
          </li>    
          <li>
            <a href="#">FAQ</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="legal">
      <p>&copy; 2021 Ccdj. All rights reserved.</p>
    </div>
  </footer> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and heres my css on footer

```
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
/* navagation bar */ 
nav{
  display: flex;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #1b1b1b;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 50px 0 100px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
nav .logo{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
nav ul{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
}
nav ul li{
  margin: 0 5px;
}
nav ul li a{
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
nav ul li a.active,
nav ul li a:hover{
  color: #111;
  background: #fff;
}
nav .menu-btn i{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"]{
  display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 1000px){
  nav{
    padding: 0 40px 0 50px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 920px) {
  nav .menu-btn i{
    display: block;
  }
  #click:checked ~ .menu-btn i:before{
    content: "\f00d";
  }
  nav ul{
    position: fixed;
    top: 80px;
    left: -100%;
    background: #111;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }
  #click:checked ~ ul{
    left: 0;
  }
  nav ul li{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 40px 0;
  }
  nav ul li a{
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -100%;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  }
  #click:checked ~ ul li a{
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  nav ul li a.active,
  nav ul li a:hover{
    background: none;
    color: cyan;
  }
}
/* Manage .php*/
.container1{
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ffffcc;
  margin: 40px auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 40px;
}
.ps{
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;  
  font-size: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: black;
}
/* footer */
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  padding: 30px 30px 20px 30px;
  color: #2f2f2f;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.footer > * {
  flex:  1 100%;
}

.footer-addr {
  margin-right: 1.25em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.footer-logo {
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.footer-addr h2 {
  margin-top: 1.3em;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.nav-title {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.footer address {
  font-style: normal;
  color: #999;
}

.footer-btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 36px;
  max-width: max-content;
  background-color: rgb(33, 33, 33, 0.07);
  border-radius: 100px;
  color: #2f2f2f;
  line-height: 0;
  margin: 0.6em 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0 1.3em;
}

.footer ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.footer li {
  line-height: 2em;
}

.footer a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.footer-nav > * {
  flex: 1 50%;
  margin-right: 1.25em;
}

.nav-ul a {
  color: #999;
}

.legal {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  color: #999;
}

.heart {
  color: #2f2f2f;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 24.375em) {
  .legal .legal-links {
    margin-left: auto;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 40.375em) {
  .footer-nav > * {
    flex: 1;
  }
  
  .footer-addr {
    flex: 1 0px;
  }
  
  .footer-nav {
    flex: 2 0px;
  }
}
.imgs {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 640px;
  padding: 0;
}

.imgs li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 181px;
  margin: 0 12px 30px;
}

.imgs li > a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 137px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 4px solid #ffffff;
  outline: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #DDD;
}
.imgs .details {
  margin-top: 13px;
}

.imgs .details h3 a {
  color: #303030;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.imgs .details {
  display: block;
  color: #717171;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
}
```

i want the view on desktop browser just like in the mobile mode my sticky responsive footer
in desktop browser i can't see the full of my last body content and name descriptions. as you can see in the picture it cut half my last row content.

Comment: Where is your image code in css or html?
I mean where is your img tag or background-image property?

Comment: paste your complete code

Comment: is this an angular application ?

Comment: already edited. just using pure html css. and php mysql

Answer (score 1):

The page is scrolling to the bottom but as you say the footer is sticky so that stays at the bottom as well. Add a margin to the bottom of your final element before the footer which looks as if it's your `<table>`. The margin would need to be the same height in pixels as the footer. That new margin will be the thing hidden whilst your page continues to scroll a little further.